# Display category AND sub category in post URL - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to customize my post URL (wordpress).

I use parent category and child category.

If i publish a post from child category, the URL is :
domain.be/category/subcategory/post-title

but if i select the subcategory and the parent category, the url is :
domain.be/category/post-title

i need, if i select the both, the url with cat and subcat.

In Wordpress BO > setting > permalink :

[image]

i don't want to use a plugin

Answer (score 0):

First of all, When modifying the url permalink structure it is best practice to flush the rewrite rules using the Wordpress `flush_rewrite_rules()` function.

> Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/

---

You're actually on the right track, indeed you need to use `/%category%/%postname%/` in your custom permalink structure.

For the purpose of this example, let's declare two categories, a parent and a child, `Fruits` and `Tomatoes`.

```
Fruits
└── Tomatoes
```

Wordpress uses the hierarchical alphabetical order to choose which category will be used in the url permalink structure. **By default Wordpress can't display more than 1 category per level.**

| Behaviour | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **Possible** | eg: `domain.com/parent/child/grand-child/my-first-post/` |
| **NOT Possible** | eg: `domain.com/parent-1/parent-2/my-first-post/` |

If we want our url to be `domain.com/fruits/my-first-post/` we need **AT LEAST** to select the `fruits` category.

If we want our url to be `domain.com/fruits/tomatoes/my-first-post/` we need to select the `tomatoes` category **ONLY**.

On your end, you simply need to unselect yhe top level categories associated with your child category and you should be good to go.